# How to give your app to certain users free of charge?

Tags: java, android

I just added an in-app purchase to my app which unlocks extra features and I have a few questions.

- I have a friend who helped me a lot in the development process, I want to give him the extra features for free, how would I go about doing that?
- I use my own app and since I can not purchase my own IAP, how would I go about unlocking said features without making a custom build for myself?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have seen developers implement a Coupon Code feature, which allows the user to enter a code within the app that, when gotten correct, will unlock certain features. Implementation of a like feature will allow you to distribute a code to yourself and others to be used to unlock features without payment.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution to the first problem: send your friend money (cash) equivalent to what they would pay to get your app from the appstore.

Apparently there is no solution to the second problem ... apart from using two distinct Google identities.